# Re-shaping Dataframe so that Column Headers are made into Rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am trying to reshape the dataframe below.

```
          Tenor   2013M06D12   2013M06D13   2013M06D14   \
1         1           1.24         1.26         1.23   
4         2           2.01         0.43         0.45   
5         3           1.21         2.24         1.03   
8         4           0.39         2.32         1.23
```

So, that it looks as follows. I was looking at using `pivot_table`, but this is sort of the opposite of what that would do as I need to convert Column Headers to rows and not the other way around. Hence, I am not sure how to proceed in order to obtain this dataframe.

```
           Date        Tenor           Rate
1    2013-06-12           1            1.24        
2    2013-06-13           1            1.26          
4    2013-06-14           1            1.23
```

The code just involves reading from a CSV:

```
result = pd.DataFrame.read_csv("BankofEngland.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do with with a [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), a sort, a date parse, and some column shuffling:

```
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars="Tenor", var_name="Date", value_name="Rate")
dfm = dfm.sort("Tenor").reset_index(drop=True)
dfm["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dfm["Date"], format="%YM%mD%d")
dfm = dfm[["Date", "Tenor", "Rate"]]
```

produces

```
In [104]: dfm
Out[104]: 
         Date  Tenor  Rate
0  2013-06-12      1  1.24
1  2013-06-13      1  1.26
2  2013-06-14      1  1.23
3  2013-06-12      2  2.01
4  2013-06-13      2  0.43
5  2013-06-14      2  0.45
6  2013-06-12      3  1.21
7  2013-06-13      3  2.24
8  2013-06-14      3  1.03
9  2013-06-12      4  0.39
10 2013-06-13      4  2.32
11 2013-06-14      4  1.23
```

Comment: It works. Except for this line `dfm.Date = pd.to_datetime(dfm.Date, format='%YM%mD%d')` which results in the Error `ValueError: unconverted data remains: `. Is it possible to resolve this?

Comment: @FixIncome: sure.  The best way depends on how much extra junk there is after your date.  You could try adding `dfm["Date"] = dfm["Date"].str.strip().str[:10]` before to clear it away.

Comment: One further question. Currently the `Date`s associated with each tenor don't follow any order. Is it possible to order them from past(1st row) to present(last row) for each `Tenor`

Comment: @FixIncome: that's a separate question, and usually separate questions should be asked as such.  SO doesn't work in a threaded format where we solve all your problems but in a discrete Q/A format (after all, someone else might have the same problem as you but it's unlikely they'll have the same five questions.)  Anyway, you can sort on multiple columns, so you could do `dfm = dfm.sort(["Tenor", "Date"])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# try to read your sample data, replace with your read_csv func
df = pd.read_clipboard()

Out[139]: 
   Tenor  2013M06D12  2013M06D13  2013M06D14
1      1        1.24        1.26        1.23
4      2        2.01        0.43        0.45
5      3        1.21        2.24        1.03
8      4        0.39        2.32        1.23


# reshaping
df.set_index('Tenor', inplace=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df.columns=['Tenor', 'Date', 'Rate']
# suggested by DSM, use the date parser
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%YM%mD%d')

Out[147]: 
    Tenor       Date  Rate
0       1 2013-06-12  1.24
1       1 2013-06-13  1.26
2       1 2013-06-14  1.23
3       2 2013-06-12  2.01
4       2 2013-06-13  0.43
..    ...        ...   ...
7       3 2013-06-13  2.24
8       3 2013-06-14  1.03
9       4 2013-06-12  0.39
10      4 2013-06-13  2.32
11      4 2013-06-14  1.23

[12 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.set_index("Tenor").stack().reset_index().add_prefix("col_").sql().select("strptime(col_level_1,'%YM%mD%d')::date Date,col_Tenor Tenor,col_0 Rate").to_df()

Out[104]: 
         Date  Tenor  Rate
0  2013-06-12      1  1.24
1  2013-06-13      1  1.26
2  2013-06-14      1  1.23
3  2013-06-12      2  2.01
4  2013-06-13      2  0.43
5  2013-06-14      2  0.45
6  2013-06-12      3  1.21
7  2013-06-13      3  2.24
8  2013-06-14      3  1.03
9  2013-06-12      4  0.39
10 2013-06-13      4  2.32
11 2013-06-14      4  1.23
```